# Half Circle in Circle with Css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a circle with double border. I need a kind of half circle in it like below (section with arrow).

[image: What i need]

I created an inner-circle and positioned it as absolute. But i can not draw that shape properly in first circle. My result is like that. :/

[image: My result]

What should i do? Must borders be another div or can i directly draw that shape?

Thanks in advance.

My Code for First Circle:

```
**.circle** {
border: 6px solid #F8DADA;
box-shadow:
inset 0 0 0 6px #F5A6A7;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #F25858;
display: table;
position: relative;
}
```

And for inner circle or shape:

```
**.inner-circle** {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
top: 95%;
left: 50%;
margin: -35px 0px 0px -35px;
box-shadow: inset 8px 35px 0 0px #E44D52;
}
```

**Update:**

All solutions work well but Chrome do that once in a few seconds, with inner-circle solutions. But just in my project. Not with first answer (:after) or fiddle examples. I guess it's a kind of chrome bug.

[image]

**Solution For Update:**

In first circle "z-index:0" solved the last problem.

Comment: share your code, so we can check what you have tried

Comment: Have you thought about - a smaller circle inside an overflow hidden circle?

Comment: why don't you use <svg> ?

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: I never used svg. I will search. :/

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd6koq0r/). It was not so difficult :)

Comment: @MohammadUsman OP wants a *half* circle, not a complete circle. But your code can be extended to fit this use case.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. It was pretty hard for me. :)

Comment: No i wanted exactly that like in first picture. My English is weak. Sorry.

Comment: Commentary: Sometimes people need to realize that CSS is not a graphics drawing program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed inset to normal box shadow and swapped the colors between them. and used after pseudo selectors.[image]

```css
.circle{
      border: 6px solid #F5A6A7;
      box-shadow:0 0 0 6px #F8DADA;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
      background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
      margin-top: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #F25858;
      display: table;
      position: relative;
      overflow:hidden;
      opacity: 0.99;
      z-index:999
}
.circle:after{
      content:'\25BE';
      text-align:center;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color:#fff;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      padding-top:10px;
      height: 70px;
      width: 70px;
      bottom: -38px;
      left: 26%;
      box-shadow: inset 8px 35px 0 0px #E44D52;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

</div>
```

Comment: This is almost exact answer. But it's some rough where borders start due to mine. Interesting.

Comment: Without "display: table" it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

**Note:If you want Support your code in IE,Firefox,you must Remove `display: table;`**

```css
.bigCir {
border: 12px solid #F8DADA;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;

}

.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #F25858;
box-shadow:0 0 0 6px #F5A6A7;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

}  

.inner-circle {
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin: -35px 0px 0px -35px;
box-shadow: inset 8px 35px 0 0px #E44D52;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigCir">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="inner-circle">↓</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This variant is highly inefficient. Each extra `div` consume space in browser memory. Why should we use 3 `div`s if we can achieve the goal with just one?

Comment: This one and yours do something interesting Mohammad. First they seem normally but then for a few seconds inner-circle go to over first circle. Like overflow:hidden does not work. But not always. Once in a few seconds.

Comment: None of them works at in Firefox or Explorer. Just in Chrome.

Comment: Ok now. Dispaly:Table was the problem i guess. After your edit it works everywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: There is just one problem. See my update. Probably it's a bug in chrome.

Comment: There is no any error in your code examnple. It happens only i use your code in my project. Interesting. Nevermnind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `background-color` and a `radial-gradient`.

One element and a pseduo-element for the arrow.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 6px solid #F5A6A7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #F8DADA;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
  background-color: #F25858;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, red 20%, transparent 20%);
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  content: '\2193';
  font-size: 1.25em;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
  transition: bottom .25s ease;
}

div:hover::after {
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I guess, OP would be needed to have at least 2 `div`s in this particular case. As we can guess, on click of bottom half circle, user will be navigated to somewhere else in the document. So if we use a pseudo element, we can't detect that whether click event actually happened inside bottom circle.